Importing Lon/Lat points from CSV file into QGIS
I am working on locating sites in Guinea for a National Parks Infrastructure Project. I have a chart with Long/Lat and I thought I might import them by adding a Delimited Text Layer using a CSV file that this community kindly helped me do for UTM points.
Can I do these points the same way and somehow keep the reference material available in the attributes table?
I tried importing the same way and it did not work.


You should be able to import the above table as a Delimited Text Layer if its come from a CSV. What goes wrong?

Please post a snippet of your CSV file and a screen shot of how you're importing the points.
